# Can I use parse4cn1 in non cn1 projects?

Tags: codenameone, parse4cn1, parse4j

I've been trying to download the `parse4j` from Thiagolocatelli but they're missing version `1.5-SNAPSHOT` which includes a third parameter for `Parse.initialize()`, but I can't download version `1.5-SNAPSHOT` from github nor from Maven repository, people talk about version `1.5-SNAPSHOT` but looking at the Maven repository: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.thiagolocatelli/parse4j there is no version `1.5-SNAPSHOT`. So is it possible to use `parse4cn1` in non cn1 projects like Android Studio projects? Will library work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is possible to use parse4cn1 in a regular Java project as documented  [here](https://github.com/sidiabale/parse4cn1/wiki/Usage-Examples#using-parse4cn1-in-a-regular-java-project). In fact, the parse4cn1 unit test application uses this approach successfully. As already mentioned by Shai, you'll have some dependencies on some CN1-specific functionality but that is available via the CN1 JavaSE port.

For Android, I'll recommend using the native Android Parse [SDK](https://github.com/parse-community/Parse-SDK-Android) directly. The API is slightly different from that of parse4cn1 but in most cases similar. Moreover, the SDK provides more functionality such as a local data store.

Answer (score 2):

No.

The code uses `ConnectionRequest` and similar Codename One specific classes to implement parse support.

Comment: I'm not sure your claim is completely correct. The parse4cn1 unit tests run as a pure Java project using a parse4cn1 jar and the relevant CodenameOne jars.